# Stationary time series with drift

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a question regarding the ADF test.

I ran a ADF test with drift with the `urca` library in R. The result implies a stationary series with drift, which is not possible to my understanding. How to interpret this result?

Also what should be done if the first hypothesis (unit root) is rejected implying no unit root, but the second hypothesis (unit root, no drift) is cannot be rejected implying a unit root and no drift?

Thank you!